# All possible values of Hypotenuse given shortest leg.

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Three relatively prime integers are the sides of a right triangle. If the smallest leg has length 28, find the sum of all the possible values of the hypotenuse.

So far I have made an equation:

$$28^2+b^2=c^2 \Rightarrow 784+b^2=c^2$$

Given that $GCD(28,b,c)=1.$

I'm confused on what my next step should be, I'm trying to find modulos that would give me a possible solution path however I'm stuck. Could I please have a hint in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

Comment: I know what Pythagorean triples are, but I don't know how their definitions would help.

Comment: Wait, could Euclid's Formula help? $a=m^{2}-n^{2},b=2mn,c=m^{2}+n^{2}$

Comment: $784 = 49 \times 16$.  In addition to $c$ and $b$ being relatively prime to each other, they must also be relatively prime to $a$.  This means that neither $c$ nor $b$ must be divisible by either $2$ or $7$.  It also means that $(c + b) \times (c - b) = 784.$